# Ruby on Rails 4.0 - Retrieving a parameter from within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my records index, I wish to insert an icon, of which name is calculated in the model, using parameters thanks to a parameters helper.
Retrieving parameters actually does not work.

In the BusinessRules index table, I specified an image tag:

```
    <td><%= image_tag(business_rule.index_audit_tag, :alt => "Quality hit") %>
```

Which I extract from a public function in the model:

```
### display audit tag filename
def index_audit_tag
  ratio = (1-self.bad_records / (self.all_records+1)) * 100
  image_file = case ratio 
    when 0..60 then "red.png" 
    when 60..90 then "yellow-png"
#    when red_threshold..yellow_threshold then red_image 
#    when yellow_threshold..green_threshold then yellow_image
    else "green.png"
  end
  return image_file
end
```

It works fine when hard-coded, but I would like to use the red_threshold etc. parameters which are available through the parameters_helper:

```
def red_threshold
  list_id = ParametersList.where("code=?", 'LIST_OF_DISPLAY_PARAMETERS').take!
  @myparam = Parameter.where("parameters_list_id=? AND name=? AND ? BETWEEN active_from AND active_to", list_id, 'Tag 1-Green light', Time.now ).take!
  @myparam.param_value.to_i
end
```

If I try using the parameters, I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `red_threshold'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: in the model where is defined `index_audit_tag`, add `include ParametersHelper` (you might have to restart your server) -- But it is not conventionnal at all to include a Helper in a Model. Helpers are there for the controller/view code that has no place in each one. `red_treshold` should be a method of a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a helper method from within a model. Helpers are in the *view* layer of MVC and models are in thee *model* layer. To fix this you need to put both halves of the logic in the same layer.

**If you want to keep `index_audit_tag` in the model layer:**

In the `Parameter` model:
    class Parameter

```
   def self.red_threshold
      list_id = ParametersList.where("code=?", 'LIST_OF_DISPLAY_PARAMETERS').take!
      myparam = Parameter.where("parameters_list_id=? AND name=? AND ? BETWEEN active_from AND active_to", list_id, 'Tag 1-Green light', Time.now ).take!
      myparam.param_value.to_i
   end

end
```

(Note: You can probably improve this to do one query, but I'm not clear on your data model so I didn't try.)

And in your `BusinessRule` model:

```
def index_audit_tag
  ratio = (1-self.bad_records / (self.all_records+1)) * 100
  image_file = case ratio 
    when 0..60 then "red.png" 
    when 60..90 then "yellow-png"
    when Parameter.red_threshold..Parameter.yellow_threshold then red_image 
    when Parameter.yellow_threshold..Parameter.green_threshold then yellow_image
    else "green.png"
  end
  return image_file
end
```

**If you want to put the icon logic in the view layer:**

Many people would argue that the logic for choosing the right icon doesn't belong in the model. So another way to do this (and probably how I would do it) is to remove `index_audit_tag` from the model instead, and put it in a helper:

```
def index_audit_tag_for(business_rule)
  ratio = (1-business_rule.bad_records / (business_rule.all_records+1)) * 100
  image_file = case ratio 
    when 0..60 then "red.png" 
    when 60..90 then "yellow-png"
    when red_threshold..yellow_threshold then red_image 
    when yellow_threshold..green_threshold then yellow_image
    else "green.png"
  end
  return image_file
end
```

Then it will have no trouble finding the `*_threshold` methods which are also in the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot gwcoffey ! Putting the icon in the view layer is actually the right approach, and it works fine !